# Chance a player has a card given set of possible cards per player

Tags: algorithm, distribution, playing-cards

In a trick-taking game, it is often easy to keep track of which cards each player can possibly have left. For instance if following suit is mandatory and a player does not follow suit, it is obvious that player does not have any more cards of that particular suit.

This means, during the game you can build up knowledge about which cards each player can possibly have.

Is there a way to efficiently calculate (a reasonably accurate) chance that a specific player actually has a certain card?

A naive way would be to just generate all permutations of all cards left and check which of these permutations are possible given the constraints mentioned earlier. But this is not a really efficient way.

Another approach would be to just check how many others could have a particular card. For instance, if 3 players might have a particular card you could use 1/3 as the chance a particular player has a certain card. But this is often inaccurate.

For instance:

- Each player has 2 cards left
- Player A can have the AS, KS.
- Player B can have the AS, KS, AH, and KH.

Algorithm 1 would correctly find that the chance Player B has the AS is 0.
Algorithm 2 would incorrectly find that the chance Player B has the AS is 0.5.

Is there a better algorithm that would be both reasonably accurate and reasonably fast?

Comment: No, unless the player chooses randomly amongst all legal cards. For example, in a trick-taking game if a player can't follow suit and discards the jack of spades, it's less likely that they have the two of spades.

Answer (score 0):

Take a page from a book of quantum mechanics. Consider that every card is in a mix of states with probabilities - e.g. `x|AS>+y|KS>+z|AH>+w|KH>`. For 36 cards, you get 36 x 36 matrix, where initially all values are equal 1/36. Constraints are that sum of all values in a row equals 1 (every card is somewhere) and sum of all values in a column is 1 (every card is something). For your mini-example, initial matrix would be

```
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 (AS)
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 (KS)
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 (AH)
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 (KH)
(0)  (1)  (2)  (3)
```

Let A cards be 0, 1 and B cards be 2, 3. Chance of B having AS is 0.5.
Now you observe that P(0 = AH) = 0, then you set corresponding element to 0 and proportionally alter column and row values, then all other values so that sums remain 1:

```
0.33 0.22 0.22 0.22 (AS)
0.33 0.22 0.22 0.22 (KS)
0.00 0.33 0.33 0.33 (AH)
0.33 0.22 0.22 0.22 (KH)
(0)  (1)  (2)  (3)
```

Adding observations P(0 = KH) = 0, P(1 = AH) = 0, P(1 = KH) = 0 gets you this matrix:

```
0.50 0.50 0.00 0.00 (AS)
0.50 0.50 0.00 0.00 (KS)
0.00 0.00 0.50 0.50 (AH)
0.00 0.00 0.50 0.50 (KH)
(0)  (1)  (2)  (3)
```

As you can see, P(2 = AS or 3 = AS) = 0, as it should be.
Note that most games allow the player to shuffle the cards in his or her hand (i.e. when B plays a card, you don't know if it's (2) or (3)). Suppose A and B exchange cards (1) and (2) - this leaves matrix the same - and then when B shuffles his cards, the matrix becomes

```
0.50 0.25 0.00 0.25 (AS)
0.50 0.25 0.00 0.25 (KS)
0.00 0.25 0.50 0.25 (AH)
0.00 0.25 0.50 0.25 (KH)
(0)  (1)  (2)  (3)
```

Also note that the model isn't perfect - it doesn't allow to note observations like "B has either (AS, KH) or (AH, KS)". But in certain definitions of "reasonably accurate", it probably is.